# Setting space between bibliography entries under bibtopic

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, bibtex, pdftex, natbib

I am using package `bibtopic` to display multiple bibliographies in a single document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{natbib,hyperref}
\usepackage{bibtopic} % For multiple bibliographies

%\setlength{\bibsep}{6pt} % Space between entries
\bibliographystyle{is-unsrt}

\begin{document}
...
    \subsection*{Some heading}
        \begin{btSect}{BookList1}
        \btPrintNotCited
        \end{btSect}
...
    \subsection*{Some other heading}
        \begin{btSect}{BookList2}
        \btPrintNotCited
        \end{btSect}
...
\end{document}
```

While using the package `natbib`, I used to set the space between individual bibliography entries with line `\setlength{\bibsep}{6pt}`. Under package `bibtopic`, that is not effective.

How can I set the space between individual bibliography entries under package `bibtopic`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bibtopic/bibtopic.pdf) of `bibtopic` states that the package is compatible with `natbib`. So the following code sets the space between entries to `24pt`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibtopic} % For multiple bibliographies

\setlength{\bibsep}{24pt} % Space between entries
\bibliographystyle{is-unsrt}

\begin{document}
...
    \subsection*{Some heading}
        \begin{btSect}{books}
        \btPrintNotCited
        \end{btSect}
...
    \subsection*{Some other heading}
        \begin{btSect}{articles}
        \btPrintNotCited
        \end{btSect}
...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you need to use the `numbers` option for `natbib` if you want to use a numeric bibliogaphy.

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer.